# Sidekiq cannot connect to Redis server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I try to apply sidekiq for my project on my MacOS. Firstly I try to start redis:

```
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

After that, I start sidekiq:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

But I meet following exception:

> getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

It looks like that sidekiq cannot connect to redis server. Here is my project configuration for sidekiq:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis:6379' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis:6379' }
end

Sidekiq.default_worker_options = {
  retry: false
}
```

But if I remove configuration in my rails project, sidekiq can connect to redis. So I think there is "something wrong" with above configuration.

Please help me which part have I wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that you provide wrong url to `redis`

As far as I know, default url to `redis` is `redis://localhost:6379`, not `redis://redis:6379`. Please, try it out, it may help.